# How to use my own service definition for a security firewall guard in Symfony 4.2?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a service defined in `services.yaml` that has a `calls` entry since I don't want to specify my dependencies in it's constructor so I use setters.

Now I am trying to point the `security.firewalls.main.guard.authenticators.0` configuration entry to it, but if I try to reference it like this: `'@App\Service\Authentication\Guard'` I get *The service "security.authentication.provider.guard.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "@App\Service\Authentication\Guard".*

If I specify just the name of the class as per Symfony's docs: `App\Service\Authentication\Guard` then there's no exception and the guard works, however the `calls` section of my definition is completely ignored and thus my setters don't work.

My best guess would be that the security module uses it's own service locator that's somehow disconnected and ignores definitions in `services.yaml`, which is probably why you won't find examples of the above config entry using simple service names rather than canonical class names.

Comment: Which parts of the docs are you following?  The security bundle's dependency injection does all kind of interesting stuff to build the firewalls.  Not really surprising that it might be ignoring the app stuff.  Back in the bad old days, before the guard component, there was a multi-page procedure for implementing your own changes.  Not fun.

Comment: One possible workaround is to use the '@required' annotation to inject your dependencies.  Probably won't work but maybe worth a try.